# How can I validate two or more modals ?

Tags: jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)   and integrates the [jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

I can only validate a modal :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Validate
// http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

    $('.form-horizontal').validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      subject: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
      },
      message: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
      }
    },
    highlight: function(label) {
        $(label).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function(label) {
        label
            .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.control-group').addClass('success');
    }
  });

}); // end document.ready
```

Comment: an example but does not work well is the one on this page

Comment: http://www.aperfectmix.com/free_web_design/modal-contact-form.html

Comment: hello friends does not work yet, I'm doing wrong?

Comment: remove this line                                       $(document).ready(function(){                                         remove this line  }); // end document.ready                        not work      help please